# Who is using the W735EQ plugin?

Tags: plug-ins, equalization, mixing, recording, sound-design

hi guys,

i downloaded the demo and need to say, it's special but very nice!

there are so many choices out there, what kind of equalizer do you prefer for sound-design?

Comment: DMG Equality is a great EQ

Answer (score 1):

I prefer [FabFilter](http://www.fabfilter.com) [Pro-Q](http://www.fabfilter.com/products/pro-q.php) and for compressor [Pro-C](http://www.fabfilter.com/products/pro-c.php).

FabFilter has excellent user interface and very advanced features for mix and mastering (LR,MS, Oversampling, Solo for bands etc.)

Highly recommended!!!

If you want vintage equalizer try TubeTech emulation from [Softube](http://www.softube.com).

[PE 1C](http://www.softube.com/tubetech_pe1c.php) - Excelent Bass management and analog feel - good for punch for smashes :)

**Of course this is my personal opinion!**

Comment: Now with big sales....

Answer (score 0):

Anything really flexible, with good overall sound quality.  The Waves Q-10 works well.  The parametric EQs in iZotope's products also work.  It is also helpful to have a really good notch filter available to deal with certain types of noises--again the Q-10 can be set up that way, though my favorite is an old plug-in I have called the Blue Filter.

Answer (score 0):

DMG EQuality has been really good to work with for me. I like the analyzer, the linear phase mode, the MS functionality, the narrow q possibilities and deep notching. The filter variety is nice too.